# Set next N values to False when True found in pytorch

Tags: python, pytorch, boolean

Given a bool tensor in pytorch, I would like to have a "lockout period" of `N` values after each `True` value along each row. More specifically, in the example below, moving from left to right on any given row I would like to ensure that after each `True` the following `N` values are all `False`.

e.g.

```
N = 3
input = tensor([[0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1],
                [1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1]])
# should output
tensor([[0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
        [1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1]])
```

I can solve this with a double loop e.g.

```
for row in input:
   for element in row:
      # if sum of previous N entries > 0 set input[row,element] = 0
```

However I would like to solve this either (a) without looping at all or (b) with just a single loop (e.g. `for column in input`). Is there a way to achieve preferably (a), or otherwise (b)? I cannot assume the input tensor will be sparse or have any paritcular distribution.

Comment: @Nagakiran I have added some further detail to my question. Does this clarify what I mean?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Naga for the (Edit: since deleted) answer, but I need a pytorch solution and I am not sure that solution is `O(n)` as stated.

I found the following solution (looping over columns) seems to do the trick.

```
input = input.to(torch.bool)
for i, col in enumerate(input.t()):
   input[:,i+1:i+1+N] = torch.mul(~col, input[:,i+1:i+1+N].t()).t()
```

---

Additionally based on a quick comparison on the sort of array size I'm interested in, it seems to be around 5x faster.

```
def a():
    input = torch.randint(high=2, size = (200,100))
    input = input.to(torch.bool)
    N = 10
    for i, col in enumerate(input.t()):
        input[:,i+1:i+1+N] = torch.mul(~col, input[:,i+1:i+1+N].t()).t()

def b():
    N = 10
    a = np.random.randint(0, high=2, size = (200,100), dtype=int)
    inds = np.where(a==1)
    for r,c in np.nditer(inds):
        if a[r,c]==1: 
            a[r,c+1:c+N]=0

%timeit a()
# 100 loops, best of 5: 2.47 ms per loop

%timeit b()
# 100 loops, best of 5: 12.8 ms per loop
```